# Transform a SPFX TS without JS framework to a React TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, render, spfx

I used yo @microsoft/sharepoint to created a webpart to display a list of items.
The solution was created without Javascript framework.

```
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

import styles from './GetSpListItemsWebPart.module.scss';
import * as strings from 'GetSpListItemsWebPartStrings';

import {
  SPHttpClient,
  SPHttpClientResponse   
} from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import {
  Environment,
  EnvironmentType
} from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';

export interface IGetSpListItemsWebPartProps {
  description: string;
}
export interface ISPLists {
  value: ISPList[];
}

export interface ISPList {
  ID:string;
  Title: string;
  Summary : string;
  NewsCategory: string;
  Created:string;


    AttachmentFiles:{
      Name:string;
      Url:string;
    ServerRelativeUrl: string;
    }



}

export default class GetSpListItemsWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IGetSpListItemsWebPartProps> {
  private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
    return this.context.spHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('News')/items?$select=*&$expand=AttachmentFiles",SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
        .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        return response.json();
        });
    }
    private _renderListAsync(): void {

      if (Environment.type == EnvironmentType.SharePoint || 
               Environment.type == EnvironmentType.ClassicSharePoint) {
       this._getListData()
         .then((response) => {
           this._renderList(response.value);
         });
     }
   }



      public titleurl(query:string){
        var path="/Lists/News/DispForm.aspx?ID=";
        var currdir=this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;
       var result=currdir+path+query;


        return result;

      }

    private _renderList(items: ISPList[]): void {
      let html: string = '<table border=1 width=100% style="border-collapse: collapse;">';
      html += '<th>ID</th><th>Title</th> <th>Summary</th><th>Created</th><th>Attachments</th>';
      items.forEach((item: ISPList) => {
        html += `
        <tr>     
        <td>${item.ID}</td>       
            <td><a href="${this.titleurl(item.ID)}">${item.Title}</a></td>
            <td>${item.Title}</td>
            <td>${item.Created}</td>
            <td>
            <img src="${item.AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl}" width="300px" height="300px" />
            </td>

            </tr>
            `;
      });
      html += '</table>';

      const listContainer: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#spListContainer');
      listContainer.innerHTML = html;
    }

  public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <div class="${ styles.getSpListItems }">
        <div class="${ styles.container }">
          <div class="ms-Grid-row ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white ${ styles.row }">
          <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-u-lg10 ms-u-xl8 ms-u-xlPush2 ms-u-lgPush1">
          <span class="ms-font-xl ms-fontColor-white">Welcome to SharePoint Modern Developmennt</span>
          <p class="ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white">Loading from ${this.context.pageContext.web.title}</p>
          <p class="ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white">Retrive Data from SharePoint List</p>
        </div>
      </div> 
          <div class="ms-Grid-row ms-bgColor-themeDark ms-fontColor-white ${styles.row}">
          <div>NEWS List Items</div>
          <br>
           <div id="spListContainer" />
        </div>
      </div>`;
      this._renderListAsync();
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**This part was rendered successfully.**

I then created a solution  yo @microsoft/sharepoint
using the React option.
I am stuck on how to render the HTML documents.
Previous it as used to this.domElement, but it says It is not in the class.
I attempted to creating another class to render seems unsuccessful.
How to print the results?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './B.module.scss';
import { IBProps } from './IBProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

import {
  SPHttpClient,
  SPHttpClientResponse   
} from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import {
  Environment,
  EnvironmentType
} from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
export interface ISPLists {
  value: ISPList[];
}

export interface ISPList {
  ID:string;
  Title: string;
  Summary : string;
  NewsCategory: string;
  Created:string;


    AttachmentFiles:{
      Name:string;
      Url:string;
    ServerRelativeUrl: string;
    }



}



export default class B extends React.Component<IBProps, {}> {



  public render(): React.ReactElement<IBProps> {



    return (

      <div  className={ styles.b }>      
        <div id="spListContainer"></div>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
              <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export class shownews extends B{
  constructor(prop){
          super(prop); 

          public _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
            return this.context.spHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('News')/items?$select=*&$expand=AttachmentFiles",SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
                return response.json();
                });
            }
            public _renderListAsync(): void {

              if (Environment.type == EnvironmentType.SharePoint || 
                       Environment.type == EnvironmentType.ClassicSharePoint) {
               this._getListData()
                 .then((response) => {
                   this._renderList(response.value);
                 });
             }
           }



              public titleurl(query:string){
                var path="/Lists/News/DispForm.aspx?ID=";
                var currdir=this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;
               var result=currdir+path+query;


                return result;

              }

            private _renderList(items: ISPList[]): void {

              let html: string = '<table border=1 width=100% style="border-collapse: collapse;">';
              html += '<th>ID</th><th>Title</th> <th>Summary</th><th>Created</th><th>Attachments</th>';
              items.forEach((item: ISPList) => {
                html += `
                <tr>     
                <td>${item.ID}</td>       
                    <td><a href="${this.titleurl(item.ID)}">${item.Title}</a></td>
                    <td>${item.Title}</td>
                    <td>${item.Created}</td>
                    <td>
                    <img src="${item.AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl}" width="300px" height="300px" />
                    </td>

                    </tr>
                    `;
              });
              html += '</table>';


              const listContainer = React.createElement('h1',{},html);
              ReactDOM.render(listContainer, document.getElementById('spListContainer'));
               this._renderListAsync();

            }

  }

}
```

I do apologize If there are many tutorials on SPFX, REACT JS on CRUD operations.
However, I clone it, attempted to npm install or npm i -g, none of the repositories work for me.

**2020-01-28**

- Rewrote the code to get json directly. The html tags won't render

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './A.module.scss';
import { IAProps } from './IAProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { PageContext } from "@microsoft/sp-page-context";
import { HttpClient, IHttpClientOptions, HttpClientResponse, SPHttpClient, ISPHttpClientOptions, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

import {
  Environment,
  EnvironmentType
} from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';


export interface ISPLists {
  value: ISPList[];
};

export interface ISPList {
  ID:string;
  Title: string;
  Summary : string;
  NewsCategory: string;
  Created:string;
    AttachmentFiles:{
      Name:string;
      Url:string;
    ServerRelativeUrl: string;
    };

}


export default class A extends React.Component<IAProps, {}> {


  public test:any=[];
  public data:any=[];

  public geturl(query:string){
    var path="/Lists/News/DispForm.aspx?ID=";
    var currdir=this.props.pagecontext.web.absoluteUrl;
   var result=currdir+path+query;

    return result;

  }
  private getListData(){
    const opt: ISPHttpClientOptions = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose' } };

    return this.props.SPHttpClient.get(this.props.pagecontext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('News')/items?$select=*&$expand=AttachmentFiles",SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,opt)
        .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
          response.json().then((json: any) => {


            for(let i=0;i<json.value.length;i++){
              this.data.push(<div><tr>
            <td>${json.ID}</td>
            <td><a href="${this.geturl(json.ID)}">${json.Title}</a></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>${json.Created}</td>
            <td><img src="${json.AttachmentFiles.ServerRelativeUrl}" width="300px" height="300px" /></td>
            </tr></div>);

              }
            });
          });
    }








     /*
  private renderList(item: ISPList[]): void {
         item.forEach((item: ISPList) => {
                       this.data.push(`<tr>
            <td>${item.ID}</td>
            <td><a href="${this.geturl(item.ID)}">${item.Title}</a></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>${item.Created}</td>
            <td><img src="${item.AttachmentFiles.ServerRelativeUrl}" width="300px" height="300px" /></td>
            </tr>`
                       );


                           })
                           console.log(this.data);


    };

    */
/*
    private push() {
      this.test.push(1);
      this.test.push(2);
      this.test.push(3);
      console.log(this.test);
    }
    */






  public render(): React.ReactElement<IAProps>{
    this.getListData();
    console.log(this.data);


     return (


      <div id="splist">


              TEST
        <table className={styles.container}>

          <tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>Title</th> <th>Summary</th><th>Created</th><th>Attachments</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>     
    <td></td>       
            <td><a href="${this.titleurl(item.ID)}">TITLE</a></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Created</td>
            <td>
                 </td>

            </tr>

       {this.data} 

1234
        </table>
         </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**2020-01-28 18:15**

- This Don't Work this.
  If I .push (data);
  The Table would have ); all over the place.

```
this.setState({ items:"<td>{item.ID}</td> 
<td>{item.Title}</td> 
<td>{item.Summary}</td> 
<td>{item.Created}</td> 
<td>{item.AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl}</td>" });
```

**This do not work**

```
this.Title.push(<span><td>{item.Title}</td></span>); 
this.Url.push(<span><td>{item.AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl}</td></span>);
```

**This Works**

```
this.ID.push(item.ID); /* this.Title.push(<span><td>{item.Title}</td></span>); this.Url.push(<span><td>{item.AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl}</td></span>); */ this.forceUpdate();
```

If I use an array and use .push to send data including HTML tags
the follow screenshot shows the problem.
[image: ScreenShot for using array.push(<tr><td>{item.ID}</td></tr>);]

The Code

```
 public renderList(item: ISPList[]): void {

          item.forEach((item: ISPList) => {

          this.data.push(<tr>);
          this.data.push(<td>{item.ID}</td>);
          this.data.push(<td>{item.Title}</td>);
          this.data.push(<td>{item.AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl}</td>);
          this.data.push(</tr>);
//some brackets...
```

**2020-01-28 1956 Problem TR WITHIN TR**
[image: Tr within a DIV]
Problem: If I write the HTML tags and data in one line the tags will generate it self. But in the render method, I need to add a tag to wrap it   will make my output incorrect format.

```
//some codes before to get the JSON data
 this.data.push(<tr>
            <td>{item.ID}</td>
            <td>{item.Title}</td>
            <td>{item.AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl}</td></tr>);
//some more codes
```

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IAProps>{


     return (

      <div id="splist">

              TEST
        <table className={styles.container}>

          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
          <th>Attachments</th>
          </tr>

         {this.data}

         </table>      
         </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to think about your solution in terms of components (having props or states) that you want to render. In context of your solution you can create a component lets say: 'GetandRenderListItems.tsx' and do all ' _getListData()' stuff. You can use 'componentDidMount()'  life cycle hook to call _getListData() function everytime after the component is mounted. Then you need to write html template to render retrieved data (all what you have done in '_renderList()' method) have a look at below snippet to get an idea:

```
     public render(): React.ReactElement<IyourcomponentsProps> {
    return (
     // your dynamic table html and you should not use inline style but define styles in 
       scss file and use them.
    );
  }
```

Then in your 'yourwebpart.ts' file you can render this component in render() method:

```
     public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IyourwebpartProps > = React.createElement(
      GetandRenderListItems,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
       // similarly assign values to  other props
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }
```

Hopefully this will help.

**Edit**

you could use *array.map()* e.g. To render a table using your array you could write something like that.

```
    public render () : React.ReactElement<IyourcomponentsProps> {
    return(
        <div className={styles.someStyle} >   
          <table className={styles.container}>
           <tr>
             <th>ID</th><th>Title</th> <th>Summary</th><th>Created</th 
             <th>Attachments</th>
           </tr>

               { yourArray.map(function(item,key){    
                  let url = this.titleurl(item.ID);
                return (<tr className={styles.rowStyle} key={key}>    //you can use key if you want to track index
         <td></td>           <td className={styles.someclass}><a href={url}>{item.Title}</a></td>    

                  </tr> ); 
              })}    

          </table>    
        </div>    


    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

How ever I rewrite it and the array won't render
I am trying to print the html tags and hopfully to completes the table 
1.  tried pushing the array  using ``
2. tried pushing the array using the html tags wrap  e.g. this.data.push(<tr><td>data</td></tr>);

```

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the code snippet to give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited my question
I am unable to render using a few  set state, or an array push into the render method.

Comment: I cannot understand from your edited question that what are you trying to do. If you are into using states, i can't see it's interface.neither you have include the state in class definition. 'export default class A extends React.Component<IAProps, {}>' is not referring any state.

Comment: Provided the State was set correctly. render method does not show the data and HTML tags.
I went back to define an array and use the fetched JSON data assign to the array and use the push the array using HTML tags wrapped and display all the contents of the array in the render method.
which has )'; and buggy parts.

See screenshots above.

Comment: you have changed the whole question :p

Comment: where is the code that has produced the result you've attached?

Comment: `
 public renderList(item: ISPList[]): void {

          item.forEach((item: ISPList) => {

          this.data.push(<tr>);
          this.data.push(<td>{item.ID}</td>);
          this.data.push(<td>{item.Title}</td>);
          this.data.push(<td>{item.AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl}</td>);
          this.data.push(</tr>);
//some brackets...
`
this is the code :)

Comment: i don't get what are you trying to achieve, pushing content in array on different indexes for each item in array. Anyway, if you simply want to print html + values, you must first compose a string in foreach loop e.g.  html += "<tr><td>"+item.id+"</td></tr>"
then after loop finishes, just push composed string in the array i.e. this.data.push(html); i hope this does what you want

Comment: The updates are above
2020-01-28 18:15.
I am trying to list the news from SP.

The codes above were showing I used an array to store the HTML codes and data and render this information creating a table.
`this.data.push(<tr>);
this.data.push(<td>{item.ID}</td>);`

However this shows up.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6XaN.png

I try to make into one line
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcoSp.png

If I use state, it  won't show the data with HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

I used .bind .map functions to make it happen.
For adding state to the project should be next upate.
I was struggling on handling the arrays and trouble printing

The entire component .tsx file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './A.module.scss';
import { IAProps } from './IAProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { PageContext } from "@microsoft/sp-page-context";
import { HttpClient, IHttpClientOptions, HttpClientResponse, SPHttpClient, ISPHttpClientOptions, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import {
  Environment,
  EnvironmentType
} from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';

export interface ISPLists {
  value: ISPList[];
};

export interface Istate {
  ID:string;
  Title: string;
  isLoad?: boolean;
  Url:string;
    AttachmentFiles:{
      Name:string;
      Url:string;
    ServerRelativeUrl: string;

    };
}


export interface ISPList {
  ID:string;
  Title: string;
  Summary : string;
  NewsCategory: string;
  Created:string;
    AttachmentFiles:{
      Name:string,
      Url:string,
    ServerRelativeUrl: string,
    };

}





/*
MAIN STARTS HERE
 2020-01-28
*/ 
export default class A extends React.Component<IAProps> {

constructor(props){
  super(props);

   this.loadNews();
   this.getListData=this.getListData.bind(this);
   this.geturl=this.geturl.bind(this);
   this.loadNews=this.loadNews.bind(this);
}



//variables to render html tags
private ID:any = [];
private Title:any = [];
private Url:any = [];
private data:any =[];
private tro:any=[]; //<tr>
private trc:any=[]; //</tr>
private tdo:any=[]; //<td>
private tdc:any=[]; //</td>




private loadNews(){
  this.getListData();
  /*
  this.getListData().then((response) => {
    this.renderList(response.value);

  });
  */ // when getlist and redner list are different functions
}



  public geturl(query:string){
    var path="/Lists/News/DispForm.aspx?ID=";
    var currdir=this.props.pagecontext.web.absoluteUrl;
   var result=currdir+path+query;
       return result;
   }

private tags(flag:boolean,first:boolean){
  // if first data add <tr>
  //if last data add </tr>
  //
  if (flag && first){
    document.getElementById("tro").innerHTML = <tr>;
  }else if (flag && !first){
   document.getElementById("trc").innerHTML = </tr>;
  }

}


   private  getListData() {
    const opt: ISPHttpClientOptions = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose' } };
    this.props.SPHttpClient.get(this.props.pagecontext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('News')/items?$select=*,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles/Title&$orderby=ID desc", SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, opt).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
      response.json().then((json: any) => {
         for(let i=0;i<json.value.length;i++){
          var url=this.geturl(json.value[i].ID);
            if(i==0){ // add tags <tr> </tr>
              let flag=true; let first=true;
              this.tags(flag,first);


            }else if(i==json.value.length){
              let flag=false; let first=false;
              this.tags(flag,first);

            }
            this.data.push({ID:<td>{json.value[i].ID}</td>,
             Title:<td><a href={url} target="_blank">{json.value[i].Title}</a></td>,
             Url:<td><img src={json.value[i].AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl} width="300px" height="300px" /></td>
              });
             //   debugger;
                              this.ID.push(json.value[i].ID);

                             // this.Title.push(json.value[i].Title);
                              //this.Url.push(json.value[i].AttachmentFiles[0].absoluteUrl);
               this.forceUpdate(); 
              }//close for
        });// close response.json  
      });//close private getListData method

    }


              // json.value[i].Title}
       //json.value[i].AttachmentFiles[0].absoluteUrl}

       /*
      <td><a href="${this.geturl(json.ID)}">${json.value[i].Title}</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>${json.value[i].Created}</td>
        <td><img src="${json.AttachmentFiles.ServerRelativeUrl}" width="300px" height="300px" /></td>
         */











  public render(): React.ReactElement<IAProps>{
    console.log(this.data);
       return (
    <div className={styles.a} >
             <div className={styles.container} ></div>

         <span className={ styles.title }>News</span>
         <div className={styles.Table}>  
          <div className={styles.Heading}>  
         <table >
           <tr>  
              <div className={styles.Cell}>Title</div>  
              <div className={styles.Cell}>Created</div>  
              <div className={styles.Cell}>IMGSRC</div> 
           </tr>


            <div className={styles.Cell}>
              <span id="tro"></span>
            {this.data.map((data)=>
             <div> {data.ID}</div>
            )
            }
          </div>
          <div className={styles.Cell}>
            {this.data.map((data)=>
             <div> {data.Title}</div>
                      )
            }
          </div>
          <div className={styles.Cell}>
            {this.data.map((data)=>
             <div> {data.Url}</div>
            )
            }
              <span id="trc"></span>
          </div>








            </table>
                     </div>

                  </div>
                        </div>


    );
  }
}
```

In render method **.map function** as follows

```
 <div className={styles.Cell}>
            {this.data.map((data)=>
             <div> {data.Url}</div>
            )
            }
              <span id="trc"></span>
          </div>
```

To access data objects within array must declare **.bind** in the constructor after defining the class.

```
export default class A extends React.Component<IAProps> {

constructor(props){
  super(props);

   this.loadNews();
   this.getListData=this.getListData.bind(this);
   this.geturl=this.geturl.bind(this);
   this.loadNews=this.loadNews.bind(this);
}



//variables to render html tags

private data:any =[];
```

[image: Prototype, Halfway through the project.]
Halfway through.
This is the prototype.
once I am able to extract the data , I can then style the CSS

Thank you for your help.